# Azure Data Factory and Marketing Cloud connector

Tags: marketing-cloud, azure

We are looking to copy data from marketing cloud to Azure data factory, looking at [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-salesforce-marketing-cloud) it says that does not support custom object and custom data extensions. 
Does anyone know what it means? it is a bit vague. Also what is supported? can we export emails results, journey results, data views?

The goal is to enable the data analysis team to interrogate the data from MC

thanks